# I want to make a command that the bot can log a edited messages

Tags: node.js, discord.js

As the title said I want the bot the log a edited message but I don't know how to do it. This is what I do in log a deleted message.

```
client.on('messageDelete', message => {
    if(!message.partial) {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('819165881623773194');
        if(channel) {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle('deletedmessage').addField('message deleted ', ${message.author.tag}).addField('message deleted in', ${message.channel.name}).setDescription(message.content).setTimestamp();
            channel.send(embed);
        }
    }
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client event `messageUpdate` this will trigger every time a message has been changed.
Example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('messageUpdate', function(oldMessage, newMessage) {
    const channel = client.channels.fetch('channel-id');
    channel.send(`<@!${newMessage.author.id}> edited their message. **Old message:** ${oldMessage.content}, **New Message:** ${newMessage.content}.`);
});
```